# convert NSTextField to value in Xcode 8 for macOS

Tags: swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

hi I'm extremely new to Xcode 8 and decided I wanted to make a simple calculation app for macOS. I've learned everything online but can't make heads or tails of it because nothing I've tried works
my following code is:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var P: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Q: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var FieldP: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var FieldQQ: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var ResultLabel: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func CalculateButton(_ sender: NSButton) {

        var A = (FieldP.stringValue as NSString).floatValue

        var B = (FieldQQ.stringValue as NSString).floatValue

        var sum = A + B

        ResultLabel.stringValue = "\(sum)"

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

FieldP is where u enter a number and so is FieldQQ. I want to be able to add them upp together and the end result show up in the ResultLabel field after you've hit the calculation button. Anyone who can fix this for me and show me how it's done? Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `IBAction` is not connected to the button in Interface Builder. Check that.

Since you are new to Swift please conform to the naming convention that variable names and methods start with a lowercase letter. (If you will change the names you have to reconnect the UI elements in Interface Builder).

Unrelated to the issue `NSTextField` (actually the `NSControl` superclass) has also a `floatValue` and `doubleValue` property (don't read or watch bad tutorials which suggest such silly type casts to `NSString`) and all variables are actually constants (`let`). Consider the yellow warnings and their suggestions to fix them.

The code is supposed to be

```
@IBOutlet weak var fieldP: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var fieldQQ: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: NSTextField!

@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let a = fieldP.floatValue
    let b = fieldQQ.floatValue
    let sum = a + b
    resultLabel.stringValue = "\(sum)"

    // or even  resultLabel.floatValue = sum

}
```